# Recording audio and streaming to clients from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, getusermedia

I need to take recorded audio (I believe using the `getUserMedia()` function) and stream it to connected clients' browser from a nodejs server. I've looked around at some examples with nothing too definitive, and with varying approaches.

I can't use webrtc. It must be using a server to send a stream to clients. I can however use `getUserMedia()` (which I believe is part of webrtc) to record the audio and send it to the nodejs server).

Are there any resources or examples that show something like this working?

Answer (score 2):

[media-source-stream](https://github.com/RationalCoding/media-source-stream).

Takes your getUserMedia and send video/audio over a WebRTC DataChannel without using media channels.